# 2D Grid Based Simulation Game

Tags: html, flash, 2d, simulation, simulator

I'm not sure where to begin, but my goal is to to create a 2D simulation game that allows the user to create formations using points, or dots, on the grid. I wanted the game to allow the user to direct the points on the grid to their next location, or set of locations, in a continuous simulation from the first formation to the last in chronological order.

Like I mentioned earlier, I am brand new to coding and wanted to know what specifically should I be looking to learn to create this? Also if you have suggestions on what I should use to create this such as Flash, Html5, or something else please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make [Conway's Game of Life](http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/)?

As far as good beginner game engines go my first couple of games were in GameMaker. I understand the reputation it gets about it not having "real programming" but if you are learning to write code I actually think this works great. No it doesn't have syntax like code does, but it does require you to learn programming logic and that is what is important. Syntax isn't that tricky and you can look it up. Logic and structure, that's hard.

I don't know much about FLash other than that it is kind of a sinking ship and losing support. If it's between javascript and that, go Javascript. When you say
HTML5 or Java, you do not make games in HTML5. If you have an HTML5 game engine like Impact, it's actually javascript code you are writting. HTML5 is just putting the game window in a web page.

I haven't messed with [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/hifi.html) much, but Python is a fantastic beginner language and I have heard this works for small things like what you want to do.

[Love2D](https://love2d.org/) gets used for projects like yours a lot. Don't have experience with it myself but you could take a look at it.

I have used [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) a lot for my projects big and small. It's a big learning curve but if you want to learn how you could make "big" games, this is how you should do it. Tons of great beginner learning materials and support, just expect to go through several tutorials(which you should do anyways with whatever you pick) before you can get started.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I think to better describe what I am trying to create, it would make more sense to describe it to designing X's and O's for a football play, and simulating the execution of that play in a smooth continuous simulation. It is something that is 2D, all the pieces can be controlled and directed, and you can have each piece change direction individually.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a start pattern, and a target pattern, and the user must move the points by, say, sliding them along the grid lines, until the target pattern is attained... I think the easiest would be Corona (https://coronalabs.com/, free and excellent docs). It has a very simple game engine which is based on Lua programming language, a very simple language that is also very powerful and versatile such that it will allow you to jump in and support complexifying your game as you learn. Corona is built so you don't have to worry about all the intricacies of getting the code onto the device etc, it has a device emulator so you can test on your desktop. You just focus on creating your callbacks and logic and imagery, they will get used at the appropriate time.

The concepts you will need to develop your game: 
- setting up the initial grid and pattern
- drawing lines (for the grid) and circles (for the "points) (presumably, different colors)
- handling a swipe
- updating the state of the grid so you know where the points are 
- determining if the target pattern has been met
- keeping score (time used, number of moves required)
- start-over (prematurely with confirmation by user, or when target reached)

Install Corona, look at its intro to Lua, start playing around with it, starting with really simple stuff, actually best is to take existing examples that come with Corona and try to modify them to do something different and gradually diverge from original. The Corona docs and examples are excellent, there is a very active community, tons of youtube videos by avid game developers on tricks and techniques, and corona questions on stackoverflow get quick answers.

Have fun!